# App unresponsive while getting images from the server in NativeScript for ListView

Tags: nativescript

I am aware that NativeScript is single threaded. Building an app that requires showing 30-40 images in between screens in a list view. However, once downloaded, the images are not cached if URL is directly binded. Suppose the snippet in first-page.xml

```
<ListView images={{images}}>
<Image src={{theImageUrl}}></Image>
</ListView>
```

While traversing back and forth between first-page and second-page , the images are re-downloaded and not cached. In order to prevent this, implemented the following logic for every image:

```
imageSource.fromUrl("theImageUrl").then(function(res){
//code to save the image to either temp or the documents folder 
});
```

However, 40 images require at least 20 - 22 seconds to load, leading to high app initialization time.

A workaround could be to download the images in background and switch the images src property (theImageUrl) to local image path when the download is complete, and let the user see the app and interact with it till then.

The app becomes unresponsive with this approach, till all images are downloaded, no screen taps are being captured.

Is there a possible solution to this? Has anybody come across this? putting the image downloading on the main UI thread is what is causing the issue I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried using image-cache module - here is the link to how-to in {N} documentation aboit its usage https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/image-cache/HOW-TO.html

Comment: Also you might want to use fresco or Picasso for the Android memory handling with the images. There are plugins for both libraries

Comment: Is there any solution for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of Android when working with images the memory/performance management is a common challenge. The best way to overcome such issues is via a library like **Fresco**. You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-fresco) NativeScript plugin that enables you to use the Android Fresco library in your {N} application and display images from web or local storage.

We are currently working on an upgrade of that plugin which would bring most of the features of the Fresco library to the {N} plugin, like support for animated images, background and failure placeholders, progress bars, corner rounding, dynamic sizing (percentage) and many more.

Comment: is there any solution for iOS?